# sqli query not pulling through data with unusual characters

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using a mysqli query to pull data through:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM prices WHERE item IN " . $inString;
$data = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) 
{
    $itemssql[$z] = array('name'=>$row['item'], 'price'=>$row['current_price']);
    $z++;
}
```

I have checked the query within phpMyAdmin and the correct rows are being pulled through however the while loop is disregarding certain rows.

e.g. a row where ['item'] = '★ Bayonet'

I believe it is to do with the character '★' as other rows with the following characters are not being pulled through: '龍王', '™'

What can I do to pull these rows through and add them to the array $itemssql?

Comment: what is the value of $inString? is it contains () or not?

Comment: run this before query execution `mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8")`

Comment: May be charset problem check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12567791/3202287)

Comment: @devpro that worked for the chinese characters and the TM however not for the star. Any further suggestions?

Comment: i think u need to store star as encoded form.

Comment: @devpro I replaced ★ with -star- and used preg_replace on the php search and add into array so i search -star- and return ★.

Comment: good solution,  ,,