# Node JS - Mysql : invisible characters

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, special-characters

To simplify, I save a JSON in my Mysql database, the JSON has this form:

```
{
    "idAd": "",
    "titleAd": "F2 47m² 1340 CC",
    "dateAd": "2017-11-26",
    "priseAd": 1340,
}
```

The field "titleAd" can contain special characters, including some weird and invisible characters :p
So when I make an extraction of this field the invisible character turns into "?"
I know it's a basic and simple encoding problem but I can't find the solution.

```
{
    "idAd": "",
    "titleAd": "F2 47m² 1340? CC",
    "dateAd": "2017-11-26",
    "priseAd": 1340,
}
```

For information I have specified the type of encoding in connection to the database

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    database: 'dababase',
    charset: "utf8_general_ci"
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484706/getting-weird-characters-when-fetching-value-in-mysql-database)?